# Reverse Function

Tags: functions

I need help in solving this question

The level of the Pokémon is derived from its experience points (EXP).

$$
\mathop{EXP} = \begin{cases}
n^3\left(\dfrac{\left\lfloor\frac{n+1}{3}\right\rfloor+24}{50}\right)
 &\quad n\leq 15 \\
n^3\left(\dfrac{n + 14}{50}\right)
 &  15 < n \leq 36 \\
n^3\left(\dfrac{\left\lfloor\frac n2\right\rfloor+32}{50}\right)
 & 36 < n \leq 100
\end{cases}
$$

[Equation to calculate the Experience points](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5MCt5.png)

Where EXP is the amount of experience points required to go on to level n.
I.e.

```
Level | Next Level |    Amount of EXP to next level  |  Total Amount of EXP 
1          2                  4                                 4
2          3              13.68                             17.68
3          4              32.85                             50.53
```

Implement a function that takes in the Total Amount of EXP of a Pokémon and return the current level of the Pokémon.

Comment: As you want to write a function, e.g. want to use a computer, the easiest way would be to let the PC continue your table till level 100, pokemon can't rise higher. Then you have a look up table you can use to answer your question.

Comment: I once tried to put the sequence of experience values into the OEIS, and it was bounced...

Comment: The usual meaning of $\left\lfloor\frac{n+1}{3}\right\rfloor$ is that you take $(n+1)/3$ and round it down to an integer, that is, discard the fractional part of the quotient after dividing by $3$. So when $n=3$, then $\left\lfloor\frac{n+1}{3}\right\rfloor = 1$, not $1.333\ldots$, and $EXP = 13.5$, not $13.68$.

Answer (score 1):

You could try the following. Let $E(n)$ denote the experience at level $n$ for $n = 0,\ldots,100$. You could store $E(n)$ in an array indexed from $0$. To find the level that corresponds to a certain amount of experience $EXP$, you simply search the array (linear or binary search) until you find the level $n$ such that $E(n) \leq EXP < E(n+1)$, in which case $n$ is the level you want. You can begin by checking if $EXP \geq E(100)$, in which case $n = 100$. Using a simple binary search this approach should be quite fast.